# jsp include page parameter using a HashMap in a request attribute

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'd like to pass the HTML page title to an included jsp page but the title is passed to the view in a request attribute that happens to be a hashMap `dbTable`

This works but I don't like that I have Java mixed in with my view

```
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<% HashMap dbTable = ((HashMap)request.getAttribute("dbTable")); %>
<jsp:include page="inc_header.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="<%= \"Confirm Delete \" + ((HashMap)request.getAttribute(\"dbTable\")).get(\"strTableTitle\") + \" Data \"%>" />
</jsp:include>
```

I am only using jsp 1.2 so this doesn't work (title just shows EL statement)

```
<jsp:include page="inc_header.jsp" flush="true">
  <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="Confirm Deletion of ${dbTable.strTableTitle} data" />
</jsp:include>
```

This works in the page body

```
<h1>Confirm Deletion of <c:out value="${dbTable.strTableTitle}" /> Data </h1>
```

but this gives unterminated string error

```
<jsp:include page="inc_header.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="Confirm Deletion of <c:out value="${dbTable.strTableTitle}" /> data" />
</jsp:include>
```

Any thought on how to do this cleaner?   The header is used by all my views and I would like to build the final Title String  (e.g., `Confirm Delete` HashMap.DatabaseTitle `data` ) in each view template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to upgrade to at least JSP 2.0 to get EL in `<jsp:param>` to work. [JSP 1.2 syntax reference](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1214.html#8828) doesn't mention of any EL support in `<jsp:param>`, while [JSP 2.0 syntax reference](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref2020.html#8828) does.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of new this, I was hoping for a trick, work-around or a design refactor idea to get it to work using jsp 1.2 but cleaner than embedding Java

Comment: JSP 1.2 is pretty ancient though. It's actually already for long time out of life as well. Any chance to upgrade the servletcontainer?

Comment: I have a little influence on upgrade.  It's one of those things where approval has to go up 4 levels of management.  As painful as it is, It's easier for me to spend days trying to figure out a hack.

Comment: I see. I would just forgive the use of scriptlets and concentrate your time and effort on better projects. Good luck.