# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/el/ELException

Tags: java, web-applications

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/el/ELException`

from using

`<c:set var="testVar" value="testVal" />`

All other JSTL tags work.

jsp 1.2
Java 1.4

Howver, the above works when I view this jsp in the global container.  In other words the IT department made an entry in the server.xml file to register my web application.  It is in my web application space that I get the above error.  But it works fine if I view the jsp file when it is located outside this web app folder, I guess in some sort of default wep app for the server.

In my web application lib folder I have jstl.jar and standard.jar libraries that I was using with in Eclipse when developing locall. My Eclipse environment is set to mimic the java and jsp versions of our outdated production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a too new JSTL version for your servletcontainer. JSTL 1.0 which is designed for JSP 1.2 has the class `ELException` included in JSTL JAR file. JSTL 1.1 which is designed for JSP 2.0 doesn't have it included anymore since that's together with several EL specific classes moved to JSP 2.0 API (which is provided by the servletcontainer itself).

When you run JSTL 1.1 on a JSP 1.2 container, it'll complain that `ELException` is missing because it's not available by JSP 1.2.

So, to fix your problem, downgrade your JSTL version to 1.0. It's available [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/standard-1.0-doc/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java 1.4 is pretty old.

I would verify the version of standard.jar and jstl.jar that you're using, because the URI changed from one version to the next.  I wonder if you have different versions of the JSTL JARs on your local machine and the server.

I'd strongly recommend a JDK upgrade.  Even JDK 5 has reached the end of its support life.  You're skating on very thin ice using JDK 1.4.

Comment: I would also warmly recommend an upgrade. However, as per his question history, he's unfortunately restricted by higher managements. See comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158422/jsp-include-page-parameter-using-a-hashmap-in-a-request-attribute/4167018#4167018).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Our IT department is quick to keep all employee machines up to date.  My desktop has jre1.6.0_22.  For some reason they won't update java on the web server.  IT says they don't need 1.6 on the server, plus they don't want to make sure other applications could handle a newer Java :(

Comment: Tell your IT department that even stepping up to JDK 5 and using the -server option will result in a nice speed up for each and every app that uses it.  JDK 5 made substantial changes to the memory model and the runtime optimization of code.  They're holding back progress by sticking with JDK 1.4.  Sounds like somebody should start working on a regression test suite.