# getting error with jstl version and jsp library using in jsp

Tags: java, maven, web, pom.xml

I am creating a spring application and when I am running my application I am getting an error. My jsp is using `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The error:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/el/ELException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:273)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3729)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2132)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1600)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2222)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3321)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1363)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1209)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3729)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2132)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1600)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1442)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2222)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3321)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I am using 2.5 xsd in web.xml and my Tomcat is 5.5.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199596/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-jsp-el-elexception

Comment: class javax.el.ELException is not available on tomcat 5.5 as it suports servlet 2.0, what you need is servlet 2.1, use newer Tomcat version, 6.0 should work.

Comment: @WundwinBorn tried that but not resolved getting som e other error.now i m trying to use tomcat 6 ,see wat haapens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Tomcat is extremly outdated. Tomcat 5.5 (Servlet 2.4) does not support the jsp expression language. See this [page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for an appropriate Tomcat version. Update to Tomcat 7 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved with Tomcat 6